# Nested Horizzontal ScrollView Not Work - React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, expo, react-native-flatlist

i'm trying to make nested horizontal scrollview.
Can you show me how change this [code?](https://snack.expo.io/SkWDO5IOr)

The child horizontal scrollview not scrolls. If i remove the 'horizontal' attribute everything works fine (child scrollview moves vertically). 
I'm using android (in IOS seems works).

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a workaround. It's react native [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21436)

Answer (score 0):

you can use prop nestedScrollEnabled of ScrollView but work for Android API level 21+

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview